# Problem while applying source to <img> tag through javascript

Tags: javascript

**Hi,**

I have stored images in my database like this **images 123.jpg**

And also in my image folder

when i am fetching image name through **ajax** and applying that image like this

```
var result="<img src='folder/images 123.jpg' />"
document.getElementById("div_name").innerHTML=result;
```

I am getting this in **Firebug**

```
<img 123.jpg="" src="folder/images">
```

i dont want to replace **space** in image name with any character like **"_"**

How to make it possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are sure about quotes? Given script & html is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result="<img src='folder/images%20123.jpg' />"
```

`%20` is a SPACE (ASCII 32) in URL encoding.

Answer (score 2):

You need to URL encode the space - either replace it with a `+` or a `%20`:

```
var result="<img src='folder/images%20123.jpg' />"
```

Or:

```
var result="<img src='folder/images+123.jpg' />"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var result = "<img src=\"folder/" + encodeURIComponent("images 123.jpg") + "\" />";
```

The `encodeURIComponent` will encode the required characters for you.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace the space with a %20 and it should work.

```
var result="<img src='folder/images%20123.jpg' />"
document.getElementById("div_name").innerHTML=result;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `escape(string)` to escape the space.

```
var url = escape('folder/images 123.jpg');
var result='<img src='+ url + '/>'
document.getElementById("div_name").innerHTML=result;
```